# Functions for comparing 2 bytearrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I have two byte arrays of same length. Now i want to check if any value of the first array is different from any value of the second array. Is there any ready made functions that i can use rather than checking item by item of the arrays. I am using VC 6.0

Comment: "I am using VC 6.0" **why**? It is twelve years old, and up-to-date versions are available free from Microsoft's website. Are you still using Windows 98?

Comment: i know it is 12 years old and i have heard enough from SO regarding VC 6.0 also but its that the project is a legacy one and sells well and so still we do maintenance on that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcmp/

Answer (score 3):

I'd say you have the choice between :

- The C-inherited [`memcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcmp/) from `<cstring>`
- The C++ standard library [`std::equal`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/equal/) from `<algorithm>`

I don't know how good/bad is VC6.0 support of standard library, so `memcmp` is probably the safest here.